# Resize HTML container element does not correctly resize child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple AngularJS, JS, JQ, HTML5, CSS3 web app. I am facing the following problem: when I try to resize the part of web interface - child elements get smaller, but they cross the border line. All content is grabbed into a `<div id="resizable">` which is just `jquery-ui` resizable element:

`<script>
      $(function() {
         $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
      });
  </script>`

It looks like this:

1:

[image]

And what I want is that it \'d be like this:

2:

[image]

No content should be below the border line. What CSS rules have to be applied for child elements so they change their size according to their container element? I tried already all of available positioning, but it just don't work - elements behave identicaly.

Can anyone provide a working plunker, which would be capable of resizing child elements correctly? Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting all your heights and widths in `%`? I threw together an example in a JSFiddle, of a 3x3 grid. They are all set to a 1/3 width and height, and so resize automatically when a user resizes the outer wrap.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z4Fg/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="resizable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    ...Two more rows...
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.row {
    height:33%;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    width:33%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

#### JS

```
$('.resizable').resizable();
```

Obviously this is an example to demonstrate the concept and not code that will work directly for your site. If you could post some of your code, I can try to adapt it.